# extracting double quotes from html tags with a regex

Tags: html, regex

I'm extracting some content from a website with this pattern:

```
 ([^+]+)
```

and it outputs

```
< img src=""http://www."" border=""0""/>
```

with double quotes. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: [No no no no no no no no no no no no THE PONIES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Alas @MonsterrodVanhugenstein, while someone who’s uncommonly adept at regexes can indeed manage such extractions without batting an eyelash, at the end of the day these things [are immeasurably harder than are dreamt of in your philosophy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491).

Comment: As it stands, your current regex matches one or more non '+' symbols, and as you can see `< img src=..../>` has no '+' symbols. What are you *trying* to get out? (What input are you giving, what output do you want).

Comment: mathematical.coffee I appologize I have no idea how to work with REGEXP, the problem is more complicated than my OP makes it out to be but really simple for someone who knows how to use it. here is my problem in more detail http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15780

Answer (score 0):

your problem only makes sense if you modify your regexp.

but first of all, beware:

> *in general, what you try to achieve is not feasible using regexes. they are the inappropriate tool to do it. you will not come up with a solution 100% correct using regexes*.

having said this, try to replace `([^+]+)` with `(([^<!--]+([^<]|<[^!]|<![^-]|<!-[^-]))+)`. note that this regex assumes the following:

- there are no html comments inside the message portion
- there are no strings containing html comment openings inside the message portion
- the message portion is a valid html fragment
  (otherwise it would match eg. `<!-<!-- / message -->`)

you have been warned.

btw, the dquote doubling must be a standard escape mechanism of the imacro environment.